# How to remove list of array from another using one line of code javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two arrays in `angular`, `products` and `productsGreen`. Where product contain all the product and productsGreen has only success products.

When someone `uncheck green checkbox` I want to remove `productsGreen` from `products`. I have seen many answers they are using loops and writing multiple lines of code.

Is that possible to do in one line of code like `products.remove(productsGreen)`.

This is my array `products`

```
{
    "color": "green",
    "loc": "L1"
},
{
    "color": "green",
    "loc": "L2"
},
{
    "color": "red",
    "loc": "L5"
},
{
    "color": "red",
    "loc": "L6"
},
```

This is my array `productsGreen`

```
{
    "color": "green",
    "loc": "L1"
},
{
    "color": "green",
    "loc": "L2"
},
```

I need output

```
{
    "color": "red",
    "loc": "L5"
},
{
    "color": "red",
    "loc": "L6"
},
```

**Edit 1:**

This is my code

```
OnChangeGreen($event)
{
if(this.CheckboxGreen==true)
{
  this.CheckboxGreen=false;
  this.chartData.pop(this.mapDatagreen)  
  this.mapImageSeries.data=this.chartData;
  this.chartData.validateData();
}
}
```

Comment: why does it need to be one line?

Comment: @epascarello - That will be more fast, I am thinking.

Comment: What is the code that does it in a loop that is "slow"? You will need a loop....

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: @Clive - One line would execute more faster then multiple lines.

Comment: @R15 that is a bunch of hot air. being one line might not be faster than multiple.

Comment: I assume you want filter()

Comment: Not really - the one line version would still have to execute the same instructions somehow. If anything the function call overhead could make it slightly slower. FWIW you’re probably in the realms of premature optimisation here

Comment: @epascarello - You are saying that.. loop will be fine and I will required here loop only.

Comment: If you showed what you have done, people might be able to tell you if there is a better way.

Comment: @epascarello - Please check my updated question. I have also written first what I am doing.

Comment: @Clive - Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter an array of objects by properties. Basic idea:

```js
var data = [{
    "color": "green",
    "loc": "L1"
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "loc": "L2"
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "loc": "L5"
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "loc": "L6"
  }
];

const selectItems = filters =>
  data.filter(item => filters.includes(item.color))


console.log("red", selectItems(["red"]));
console.log("green", selectItems(["green"]));
console.log("red green", selectItems(["red", "green"]));
console.log("blue", selectItems(["blue"]));
```